# Robustness of mode-line toggle

Tags: mode-line

Here are two implementations to toggle the mode-line.  The first checks with `default-value` for `mode-line-format`.  Would this be more robust than the subsequent implementation

Looking at `default-value`, the documentation states that

```
This is the value that is seen in buffers that do not have their
own values for this variable.  The default value is meaningful for 
variables with local bindings in certain buffers.
```

This means that a buffer can have a buffer variable defined.  And if not, use the setting in `default-value`.  This means that one can have a value defined for a buffer, whilst its `default-value` is different.

Seems to me that checking with `default-value` is not robust because the actual buffer could have a different value that what `default-value` says.

```
(defvar-local ramona-mode-line-rflog nil
  "Switch for mode-line display.")

(defun ramona-mode-line ()
  "Turns the mode-line display on or off."

  (interactive)
  (setq mode-line-format
        (if (equal mode-line-format
                     (default-value 'mode-line-format))
            ramona-mode-line-rflog
          (default-value 'mode-line-format)))
  (force-mode-line-update t))

(defun ramona-mode-line ()
  "Turns the mode-line display on or off."
  (interactive)

  (if ramona-mode-line-rflog
      (setq mode-line-format ramona-mode-line-rflog
            ramona-mode-line-rflog nil)
    (setq ramona-mode-line-rflog mode-line-format
          mode-line-format nil))

  (force-mode-line-update t))
```

Comment: Robust against what?

Comment: Does using `default-value` make the function more reliable?  What can go wrong?

Comment: You are correct that if the buffer has a local value, and you use the `default-value` implementation, then that value will be lost when you "toggle": the first toggle will set `mode-line-format` to the default value, the next will set it to the `ramona-mode-line-rflog` value and then these two will alternate - the original buffer-local value is lost.

Comment: I can make a function that gets the operational value, whether the buffer-local one or the default one.